# Reconnection of Couchbase client after node wake up

Tags: memcached, couchbase, spymemcached

I'm studying the following scenario: while get/set operations to Couchbase I shutting down node(power off on virtual machine). After that, I power on the machine and waiting for Couchbase node recovery. When node's status changing to "healthy" I expect that client reconnect and get/set operations continues. But sometimes reconnection of client occurs immediately, sometime doesn't occur within a few minutes.

So my question is:
Are there some configuration on server side, or on client side that guarantee a wholly reconnection of client?

I use JavaSDK.

A small addition:
Couchbase client is based on spymemcached client. If someone knows any hints with memcached, that could solve problem, I'll be very glad to see them.

Another addition:

Client stops trying to establish connection after this exception:

`Exception in thread "Thread-122" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Got empty SASL auth mech list. 11:59:25,731 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-122) at net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread.listSupportedSASLMechanisms(AuthThread.java:99) 11:59:25,731 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-122) at net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread.run(AuthThread.java:112)`

But I can't understand, why this exception happens so irregularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a small bug with response of CouchbaseServer. It's my [discussion](http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/SPY-136) of this problem with developer of spymemcached client. Problem was solved when I hard-coded some string at this client.